# Update JIRA Service Desk SLA from Script

Tags: jira

I go the task to pause/unpause a SLA.

My attempt was using Scriptrunner, this way there was no need to develop a complete plugin.
On my development system I got it running.

What I do is, that I get the issue customfield value of the sla I have to pause.
Inside the value is a history list, adding a new pause event there and saving works, pausing the sla without moving to a new status.
I also set the boolean in the ongoing data.
The issue gets an reindex at the ende.

My problem now is, that this works so far only on my development system.
The other two systems I have tested the script wont pause the SLA.

All systems are running the same Jira 8.7.1, Servicedesk 4.7.1 and Scriptrunner 5.6.15.1-p5 versions.
All are running against a Postgres 72

Do you have an idea why the SLA pauses on one but not on a another system?

Thanks for reading this so far
Philipp

I also asked the question here:
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Service-Desk-questions/Update-SLA-from-Script/qaq-p/1464744

Answer (score 0):

Found my Answer,

the new Timeline event was created in the future.